# How does the keyboard's up and down buttons control the order of focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I ran into a problem, about the up button and the down button, to control the focus.
For example, there is a window Form1 that contains listbox and button1.
Inside the button1 click event, Form2. pops up
1., just run the program, is running Form1, then this time the window focus on the listbox
2., if I press button1, pop up Form2 and then close, the focus of the window is on the button1.
3. at this point, I want to press the keyboard up or down button so that when the Form2 is turned off, the focus is immediately on the listbox. What should I do?
Because I found that the settings of the tab key sequence, the Tab key setting seems to be unrelated to the keyboard's up and down buttons, although they can all control the focus.
So, where can I set the focus order for up and down buttons, and how to program?

What I have tried:

i tried to set the tab key,and use keydown event to handle focuse.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            this.listboxPoints.Focus();
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            this.listboxPoints.Focus();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set KeyPreview Property of Winforms to True